# using jquery .html to call function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some code where I have a button that I'd like to create a dialog.  This dialog will have a textarea in it with some populated data that will be highlighted.  I can create the dialog and textarea I'm just not sure how to put the data into the text area and how to highlight it.

```
<button id="axis-details" onclick="apikey('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>');">API Key</button>

function apikey(camerahash)
{
var $key = "http://myhost.com/notify.php/" +camerahash;
return $key;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('Please copy this key for setup: <p><textarea id=\"textbox\">'apikey(camerahash);'</textarea></p><p>For more information see: <a href=\"http://www.myhost.com/forum/2-quickstart-docs\">setup</a></p>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Axis API Key'
    });

$('#axis-details').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
});
});
```

The behavior I want is when someone clicks the button a jquery ui dialog appears.  That is easy enough.  In the dialog I want a textarea, also easy.  The part I can't figure out is that I want to put a constructed url inside that textarea (the $key variable).  Plus that url needs to be highlighted.  I can't figure out how to put that url inside the textarea and how to highlight it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to do what?   Please take your time to explain all this in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which mess we have here! hehehehe

So, first, why you don't use `.append(html)` with each part of the html for the dialog? Second, when you want to concatenate strings in javascript, you must use `+` operator. And third, to prevent the defaul event action, use `.preventDefault()`

Well, a quick fix in your code and we got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var camerahash = '<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>';
  var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
  $dialog.append('<p>Please copy this key for setup:</p>')
         .append('<p><textarea id="textbox">' + apikey(camerahash) + '</textarea></p>')
         .append('<p>For more information see: <a href="http://www.myhost.com/forum/2-quickstart-docs">setup</a></p>');
  $dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Axis API Key'
  });

  $('#axis-details').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $dialog.dialog('open');
  });
});
```

Now, highlight texts inside textareas, or set any css properties, is not possible... To do it you'll need an HTML element that accepts HTML content instead TEXT content, like a div, but it will not be editable. So, what you'll really need is a textarea and a div to have an editable area with a preview area :]

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. My problem is now that is says camerahash is undefined.  Am I doing the apikey function correctly?

Comment: camerahash must be a variable declared before you call the apikey function.. check the answer again..